# Javascript split regex question

Tags: javascript, regex, split

hello I am trying what I thought would be a rather easy regex in Javascript but is giving me lots of trouble. 
I want the ability to split a date via javascript splitting either by a '-','.','/' and ' '.

```
var date = "02-25-2010";
var myregexp2 = new RegExp("-."); 
dateArray = date.split(myregexp2);
```

What is the correct regex for this any and all help would be great.

Answer (score 226, accepted):

You need the put the characters you wish to split on in a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), which tells the regular expression engine "any of these characters is a match". For your purposes, this would look like:

```
date.split(/[.,\/ -]/)
```

Although dashes have special meaning in character classes as a range specifier (ie `[a-z]` means the same as `[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]`), if you put it as the last thing in the class it is taken to mean a literal dash and does not need to be escaped.

To explain why your pattern didn't work, `/-./` tells the regular expression engine to match a literal dash character followed by any character ([dots](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) are wildcard characters in regular expressions). With "02-25-2010", it would split each time "-2" is encountered, because the dash matches and the dot matches "2".

Comment: You could also mention that a dot *doesn't* have any special meaning inside of a character class - instead of acting as a wildcard character (which wouldn't make any sense), it acts as a literal.

Answer (score 15):

or just (anything but numbers):

```
date.split(/\D/);
```

Answer (score 6):

you could just use

```
date.split(/-/);
```

or

```
date.split('-');
```

Comment: Put a line break before your code and the 4 spaces will format it properly.

Answer (score 6):

Say your string is:

```
let str = `word1
word2;word3,word4,word5;word7
word8,word9;word10`;
```

You want to split the string by the following delimiters:

- Colon
- Semicolon
- New line

You could split the string like this:

```
let rawElements = str.split(new RegExp('[,;\n]', 'g'));
```

Finally, you may need to trim the elements in the array:

```
let elements = rawElements.map(element => element.trim());
```

Comment: Why the g-flag?

Comment: @d-b so it matches globally across the string otherwise it will only match one instance (afaik)

Answer (score 5):

Then split it on anything but numbers:

```
date.split(/[^0-9]/);
```

Answer (score 0):

or just use for date strings 2015-05-20 or 2015.05.20

```
date.split(/\.|-/);
```

Answer (score -2):

try this instead

date.split(/\W+/)

Comment: Can you explain why this is a better answer than the 5+ already posted before?  And how it actually works?

Comment: This actually worked the best out of all the answers for me.