# Split url into tab in javascript

Tags: javascript

***input:***

```
"/desh/HRTY/THR/TDR/2015-01-09?passengers=STANDARD:1&returnDate=2015-01-10&max=0&withThac=false"
```

***javascript:***

```
var params = {};
var paramDelim = link.indexOf('?');
var parmeters = link.substring(paramDelim + 1, link.length);
var parts = parmeters.split('[&=]');
```

***output of my js code:***

```
0: "passengers=STANDARD:1&returnDate=2015-01-10&max=0&withThac=false"
length: 1
```

i want to split my url into a map with key:value like this

***output:***

```
origin:THR
destination:TDR
goDate:2015-01-09
passengers:STANDARD:1
returnDate:2015-01-10
max:0
withThac:false
```

My code not do exactly what i want in output, what is wrong ?

Comment: the is no '[&=]' found on the split so this is the expected behavior

Comment: You are using a string that contains 4 characters `[&=]` as a delimiter to split. Since the input does not contain `[&=]` you're getting only one big string as your result. Try putting it in a regular expression like `...split(/[&=]/)`. This http://stackoverflow.com/a/3560051/1389366 is a very nice explanation to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should split with

```
var params = parmeters.split('&')
```

and then split all the values you get

```
for (var i = 0,len = params.length; i<len;i++){
    var data = params[i].split("=", 2);  // Max 2 elements

    var key = data[0];
    var value = data[1];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i think your wrong ' characters

```
var params = {};
var paramDelim = link.indexOf('?');
var parmeters = link.substring(paramDelim + 1, link.length);
/*--> i think used regexp. Clear ' Char. --> */var parts = parmeters.split(/[&=]/);
```

use this like..

good luck

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution using ECMA5 methods and assuming that your string is always the same pattern.

```js
var src = '/desh/HRTY/THR/TDR/2015-01-09?passengers=STANDARD:1&returnDate=2015-01-10&max=0&withThac=false',
    slice = src.split(/[\/|?|&]/).slice(3),
    data = slice.reduce(function (output, item) {
        var split = item.split('=');

        output[split.shift()] = split.shift();

        return output;
    }, {
        origin: slice.shift(),
        destination: slice.shift(),
        goDate: slice.shift()
    });

document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(data)));
```