# Javascript Splitting string

Tags: javascript

I want to split string into a tab

***input:***

```
/offers/BESTOFFERS/FRTNE/FRPAR/2015-01-09?passengers=STANDARD:1&returnDate=2015-01-10&maxVia=0&withThac=false
```

***js:***

```
link.substring(link.indexOf('/BESTOFFERS/') + 12, link.length).split('/[/?&]/');
```

***my output:***

```
["FRTNE/FRPAR/2015-01-09?passengers=STANDARD:1&returnDate=2015-01-10&maxVia=0&withThac=false"]
```

What is wrong ?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add what is the output you want to achieve?

Comment: Just a typo: regex is not a string, change to `.split(/[/?&]/);` **without quotes**. I just saw you had this answer also in your previous (duplicate) question.

Comment: What is the output you expecting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split url into tab in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27858225/split-url-into-tab-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to slit you should use split:

string[] linkParts = link.split("/BESTOFFERS/");

string array will contain:

linkParts[0] -> "/offers"

linkParts[1](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) -> "FRTNE/FRPAR/2015-01-09?passengers=STANDARD:1&returnDate=2015-01-10&maxVia=0&withThac=false"

For more information refer [JavaScript String split() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

For even more information refer [JavaScript substring, substr and slice](http://www.web-plus-plus.com/Articles/jajascript-substring-substr-slice)