# Regex isn't matching on Javascript .split() but does match on testing tool

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have this code. I am trying to match on .mono-50, where 50 can be any number.

```
imageUrl = 'http://example.com/media/image.mono-50.png';
imageUrlSplit = imageUrl.split('/.mono-\d+/');
console.log(imageUrlSplit);
```

This does not match, but does match on my testing tool, regexr.com

http://regexr.com/3e55b

I have done many variations on it including the following.

```
.split('/.mono\-\d+/');
.split('/\.mono\-\d+/');
.split('/.mono-\d+/g');
.split('/.mono\-\d+/g');
.split('/\.mono\-\d+/g');
```

All of these work in the tool, but none in Javascript. Am I misunderstanding something on how `.split()` treats Regex?

I have seen this question, but it has not helped me solve this issue.

[Javascript split regex question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559883/javascript-split-regex-question)

Comment: Remove the single quotes, as you're splitting on a string rather than a pattern.

Comment: @Trey: Not only. The dot must be escaped, too. OP is not sure whether it must be escaped or not.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew correct, but he has escaped them in some of his attempts so I didn't mention it

Comment: `'/\.mono\-\d+/g'` -> the literal string that starts with forward slash contains "mono" and finishes on forward slash and "g". `/\.mono\-\d+/g` the regex that matches a pattern that contains a literal dot, followed by "mono" dash and any number of digits.

Comment: If the dot is unescaped, then `'http://example.com/media/demono-60/image.mono-50.png'` would get split incorrectly. @Vld: the global behavior is default with `split()`. A second argument controls that side of splitting.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew true, I'm just pointing out the difference between surrounding the pattern in quotes vs not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a regex literal notation (when the regex literal is put inside quotes it becomes a regular string literal, and `split` uses this text as a literal string, not a pattern) and *escape the dot* since an unescaped dot in a regex pattern matches any character (but  a newline):

```
imageUrlSplit = imageUrl.split(/\.mono-\d+/);
                               ^^^        ^
```

See demo:

```js
imageUrl = 'http://example.com/media/image.mono-50.png';
imageUrlSplit = imageUrl.split(/\.mono-\d+/);
console.log(imageUrlSplit);
```